# EF Core not persisting changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, entity-framework

I'm working in .NET 7 with EF Core 7.0.0

```cs
private async Task ProcessNonExistingVm(Guid vmId)
{
    var vmInfo = await _context.VmInfos
        .Include(i => i.Tags)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == vmId);
    if (vmInfo is null) return;

    // Make sure VM status is Deleted
    if (vmInfo.ProvisioningState is not VmProvisioningState.Deleted)
    {
        vmInfo.ProvisioningState = VmProvisioningState.Deleted;
        // Changes aren't saved here
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    
    else if (vmInfo.UpdatedOn < DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-5))
    {
        // some other operations...
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Even though I save the changes after setting the `ProvisioningState` to `Deleted`, next time this code is executed for the same `vmId` it will be still marked as not `Deleted`.

The `ProcessNonExistingVm` is called for each vmId in another method:

```cs
// Supplied via dependency injection
private readonly SessionManagerContext _context;

public async Task Invoke()
{
    // ...
    
    // Assemble a list of VMs not present in Azure, but present in the database
    var vmsInDb = await _context.VmInfos
        .Select(info => info.Id)
        .ToListAsync();
        
    var vmsNotPresentInAzure = vmsInDb
        .Except(vmsPresentInAzure.Select(vm => vm.Id))
        .ToList();

    // Process VMs that are present in Azure
    foreach (var vm in vmsPresentInAzure)
    {
        // ...
    }
    
    // Update status of VMs and sessions that are no-longer present in Azure
    foreach (var vmId in vmsNotPresentInAzure)
    {
        try
        {
            await ProcessNonExistingVm(vmId);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to process non existing VM {VmId}", vmId);
        }
    }
}
```

This `Invoke` method is executed as a background task. After it finishes, there is a delay of 1 second and it is called again with a brand new `_context`.

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Additional info:

```cs
public sealed class VmInfo : AuditableEntity
{
    public string? VmId { get; set; }
    public VmProvisioningState ProvisioningState { get; set; }
    
    public VmPowerState PowerState { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = "Not set";
    public string? Location { get; set; }
    public List<string> PublicIPs { get; set; } = new();
    public List<string> PrivateIPs { get; set; } = new();
    public string? Size { get; set; }
    public string? OperatingSystem { get; set; }
    public List<VmTag> Tags { get; set; } = new();
    
    // Parent
    public Guid? SessionId { get; set; }
    public Session? Session { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public enum VmProvisioningState
{
    Failed = 0,
    InProgress = 10,
    Updating = 15,
    Cancelled = 20,
    Succeeded = 30,
    Deleting = 90,
    Deleted = 100,
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...
    
    var vmInfo = modelBuilder.Entity<VmInfo>();
    vmInfo.HasKey(i => i.Id);
    vmInfo.HasIndex(i => i.VmId);
    vmInfo.HasIndex(i => i.ProvisioningState);
    vmInfo.HasIndex(i => i.PowerState);
    vmInfo
        .HasMany(i => i.Tags)
        .WithOne(t => t.VmInfo)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.VmInfoId);
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems wrong in your code from the first glance. A few ideas/guesses: * are you running the code inside a transaction and not committing it? Similarly, are you for some reason turning autocommit off? Does updating the database take more than 1s so that you can theoretically hit a race condition? All wild ideas.

Comment: No, no transactions here, no strange configurations. Every query/commit is awaited so there should be no race conditions :/ The Postgres database is tiny and is running locally so no additional network latency.

Comment: Are other updates being persisted? (If all updates are affected, have change tracking proxies been disabled?) Can you put up the code for this vmInfo class, particularly around this ProvisioningState property & associated enum? If this is an auto-property eliminate any possible accidental Setters being called, and consider setting a breakpoint on the setter. If there is a backing field, eliminate any possibility of code accidentally accessing/setting it as well. It sounds like a rather strange  issue.

Comment: @StevePy The rest is being updated correctly. I agree that this is a strange issue.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on the auto-property setter by mousing over the `set` statement in the property, right clicking and selecting "Breakpoint -> Set Breakpoint" then run through your scenario with a Watch on the ID if it could get tripped for different entities.  You should find it triggered when you set it to Deleted, but let it flow through if there is some other unexpected code tripping and overriding it. Other culprits might be a trigger on the table. "When you have eliminated all which is impossible, then whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."  :)